# Retrieving element with jQuery inside knockout event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I've been playing about with knockout.js with jQuery, and I'm very new to knockout.js

My code example and code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/ADYN6/

Basically, I'm trying to create a lottery numbers input screen as a test of my knowledge, and I'm now trying to validate the input of a textbox, and then apply special effects to the input box if [onBlur], the text box is not valid.

I have a 'LotteryApp', with an observable array of 'Lines', with a normal array of [5] ko observables to serve as my inputs or 'Number Boxes'. I'm using a template to display each 'Line' and a further template inside that to render the 'Boxes'.

What I'd like is to call perhaps a jquery 'colour fade' plugin [red to bg color] on the textbox if the input isn't correct. But in the 'onBlur' function I've created, I cant find anything in any of the arguments passed to the function to help me call something like `myTextBox = jQuery(arguments.something)`, so that I can do something like `jQuery(myTextBox).colourFade()`

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:n, event:{blur: $parent.onBlur }, uniqueName:true, disable: $parent.isLD" class="lotteryNumber" maxlength="2"/>
```

is the code in my innermost template handling the onBlur.

```
self.onBlur = function()...
```

is the function I wish to call on the 'blur' event.

I am aware that if I use a custom binding e.g. `ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding` then the 'element' is passed directly to the 'update' and 'init' calls, which I can then use to call jQuery(element).colourFade(), but this is more of an exercise in understanding how to access the element using the standard event bindings, because I can imagine I'll be needing it often and dont wish to do EVERYTHING in a custom binding, and also, with only 'init' and 'update' options inside a custom binding (to my knowledge), I dont think those will be enough (e.g. what about on 'keyup'?), and anyway, the custom bindings appear to be based on a ko.observable rather than an event itself.

Summary :

when using `data-bind="event : {blur : myMethod}"`, how do I, inside of `myModel.myMethod`,  grab the html element that created the event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jQuery `event` object is the second argument in the event handler, so:

```
self.onBlur = function(data, event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks dude! "alert(jQuery(event.target).val());" returns the text box value, just as I needed it too! I'm sure I tried event.target previously, oh well, thanks for the concise answer!

Comment: note event.target does not work in IE.  you need to use event.srcElement for IE..  So, you should use something like this to handle all browsers:  var target = event.target || event.srcElement

Comment: @portlandrock: I've edited my post to point out that this is using the jQuery event object, not the one directly from the browser. If jQuery is on the page, knockout will use jQuery event handlers, which normalises the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property so that you can use it in any browser which jQuery supports.